# NuxtServerInit not working on Vuex module mode - Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

NuxtServerInit is not working on initial page render on nuxt js vuex module mode. But it works on Classic mode. Following code is the flow I used.

My api call

api/CategoryApi.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const HEADERS = {
    Accept: 'application/json'
};

export default {
    getCategory(payload) {
        return axios.get(`${process.env.apiUrl}/category`, {
            payload,
            headers: HEADERS
        });
    }
}
```

store/modules/CategoryStore.js

```
import api from '~/api/CategoryApi'

const state = () => ({
    categories: []
});

const getters = {
    allCategories: state => state.categories
};

const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({commit}) {
        const payload = {
            per_page: 6,
            page: 1
        };
        const response = await api.getCategory(payload);
        commit('setCategories', response.data.data);
    },
};

const mutations = {
    setCategories: (state, data) => {
        state.categories = data;
    }
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

pages/index.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-flex xs6 sm4 md2 class="text-xs-center my-2 pa-2" v-for="category in allCategories" :key="category.id">
            {{ category.name }}
        </v-flex>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';

    export default {
        layout: 'default',
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                allCategories: 'modules/CategoryStore/allCategories',
            })
        },
    }
</script>
```

Am I doing this wrong? :/ I want to know the right way to implement this.

**Edit: How I did with Aldarund answer** (This might help someone)

Edited store/modules/CategoryStore.js

```
const actions = {
    async fetchCategories({commit}) {
        const payload = {
            per_page: 6,
            page: 1
        };
        const response = await api.getCategory(payload);
        commit('setCategories', response.data.data);
    },
};
```

Added store/index.js

```
const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({dispatch}) {
        await dispatch('modules/CategoryStore/fetchCategories');
    },
};

export default {
    actions
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As said in the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/)

> If you are using the Modules mode of the Vuex store, only the primary
>   module (in store/index.js) will receive this action. You'll need to
>   chain your module actions from there.

So you need to place your nuxtServerInit into store/index.js

Comment: Can you please give an example of how to do that.

Comment: @Ninja it is in docs and in examples. https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/b83b5675043ebdfec3398bd83fd27dfe77cdd620/examples/auth-routes/store/index.js

Comment: Yes but my Vuex is in Module mode. So Kind of confused.

Comment: @Ninja the example i linked in module mode too

Comment: @Aldarund Not sure if your example changed, but it does not appear to be in module mode?

Answer (score 4):

try use that code, clear file index.js, and run.. on server console you see message.

```
     export const actions = {

  nuxtServerInit ({ dispatch }) {
    console.log("troololollo")
  }
}
```

maybe also can try nuxt.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  //mode: 'spa',
  mode: 'universal',
```

Comment: `mode: spa` won't make the nuxtServerInit call.  I learned this the hard way. Thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true that you can only call nuxtServerInit from within store/index.js

I think what confused me most was the difference between the modular approach and only having a single store file. In the latter approach, I would do something like:

```js
nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, {req, redirect, params})
    {
      vuexContext.dispatch('someAction',someArguments)
    }
```

Whereas when calling in a module, for example store/modules/auth.js, you cannot use the vuexContext, but instead use dispatch directly:

```js
nuxtServerInit({dispatch})
        {
          dispatch('someAction',someArguments)
        }
```

This worked for me, hope it helps

Comment: hey Andre, when you just want to indicate that it's code, you can use the "pre-code" formatting ({} icon) instead of the executable snippet formatting (<> icon).

Answer (score 0):

So many answers to these questions referencing the docs, but none mention how to actually "chain your module actions from [index.js]."

posts.js

```
export const actions = {
  // This isn't called unless it is "chained"
  nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // do a thing
      resolve()
    })
  },
}
```

index.js

```
import { actions as postActions } from './posts' ;

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      // "chain" the desired method
      await postActions.nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context)
      resolve();
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: About your new Promise with async and await. It's actually not recommended by ESLint. https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-async-promise-executor

Answer (score 0):

I've spend quite some time on this problem. I'll try to summarise my findings here with sample code to solve this issue once and for all.

Yes, the documentation from NuxtJS did said that once you structure your Vuex into modules. Then, your module's `nuxtServerInit` won't be called.

Unless you trigger it on `store/index.js`.

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Previously, our Vuex structure is like this.

```js
store/modules/user.js
store/modules/todo.js
store/index.js
```

So, you will initialise the modules in your `index.js` and for the new module way moving forward into **Vue 3**. You'll still need `index.js` to trigger your `nuxtServerInit`.

New Vuex structure for the module approach is like this.

```js
store/user.js
store/todo.js
store/index.js
```

Yes, you just need to take it our from your module package and move it to your store package.

Alright now, let's trigger `todos.nuxtServerInit` from `store/index.js`.

```js
'/store/index.js'
import todos from './todos'

const state = () => ({})
const getters = {}
const mutations = {}

const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    await Promise.all([
        todos.actions.nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context)
    ])
  },
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions,
}
```

Now, inside `store/todos.js`.

```js
'/store/todos.js'

...

const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit(vuexContext, context) {
    return await vuexContext.commit('todos/setTodos', todos)
  },
}

...
```

Remember to use `vuexContext.commit('todos/setTodos', todos)` if you're previously calling like `vuexContext.commit('setTodos', todos)`.

Because now your module is at the store package, and NuxtJS generated all the package imports for you already.

Just be aware of how your `this.$store.getters` as well, because it's now also restructured like this `this.$store.getters['todos/todos']`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do it like this ...

index.js

```
export default {
    state: () => ({
        context: undefined
    }),

    actions: {
        nuxtServerInit ({ state }, ctx) {
            state.context = () => ctx;
        }
    }
};
```

Then call it from other Stores like this ...

```
rootState.context().<some object hanging off of the context>
```